# How to connect to Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

After I created a ubuntu VM(Amazon EC2 instance), I see below entry in "view instances":

I see public dns as `Public DNS: ec2-13-58-17-118.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Instance:  `i-08c551d9713dfcd06 (ubuntu_VM)`

Security groups: `sg_ubuntu`. `view inbound rules`. `view outbound rules`

---

To connect to this Amazon EC2 instance(ubuntu VM), am using below syntax from my ubuntu laptop:

`ssh -i "ubuntu_key.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-58-17-118.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

and it works, but I do not know the reason, for its working

I understand that `ec2-13-58-17-118.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` is domain name

---

1) What is `ubuntu` in `ubuntu@ec2-13-58-17-118.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`?

2) Why Amazon EC2 instance creation process does not ask for assigning hostname to the EC2 instance, on aws website? after sshing, I see some dynamic hostname assigned(`ip-172-31-30-203`) which is not good for me...

3) What is security group? amidst creation of EC2 instance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `ubuntu` is the username of that particular ec2 instance. In this case, since your instance is using Ubuntu, then by default you get that username. If you had created an instance using Amazon Linux 2, it would of have been `ec2-user`. You can check more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html).

If you intend to change this username, you can in fact. Just like you would in any Linux OS, except for a few extra [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html) you need to follow in order to connect using SSH with this new username.

2) Each time you stop and restart your Amazon EC2 instance (unless you are using an Elastic IP address), the public IPv4 address changes, and so does your public DNS name, system hostname, and shell prompt. This is found in the user [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html). If you want to have a static IP, you must create an [Elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html), although, it has a cost.

3) The security group, is a set of rules of how to access (inbound rules) your instance and what can your server reach (outbound rules). By default, if not mistaken, in your inbound rules, you should only have your SSH connection available.

Comment: How safe is to use ec2 instance for production? Am in banking sector...

Comment: Security wise, it depends at lot in your architecture. I would recommend adding another instance and use it as a reversed proxy. Then, modifying your application instance security group, so that it can only be acceses by this proxy (of course, maintain the SSH connection). When it comes to disponilility, they are very safe as well. Still, you can automated snapshots generation and even use redundancy. You could read more about this in here.  https://cloudonaut.io/prevent-outages-with-redundant-ec2-instances/

Comment: How to get root access to the EC2 instance?

Comment: All you need to do, once you are in your server after connecting using SSH, is write the following command `sudo bash`. Then you will have full root access. You won't need a password or a username for this. Also, adding `sudo` to the start of each command should accomplish the same.

Comment: So... there is no concept of user/passwd to login to EC2 instance.... is it just private-public key combination only? What if I need to create a new user on EC2 instance and install a product with that user as owner?

Comment: I have never done it, but I know you can do it. You can follow [these steps](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-password-login/) to enable password login for your ec2 instance.

Comment: Can't I use the existing security group name  to create another EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, in fact when launching a new instance, on the step 6, which is **Configure Security Group**, you can choose to select from a existing list of security groups. Also, after the instance has been launched, you can change it by right-clicking on the respective instance and under **Networking** you will find the **Change Security Groups** option.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033755/cannot-rdp-to-amazon-ec2-instancewindows-server

Answer (score 1):

1. ubuntu is the username on the server
2. I'm not sure *why* this is, but you are able to change it using the command `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname your-desired-hostname`. You can read more in the [AWS UserGuide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html)
3. Security groups are firewall rules that you can use to protect your VM from the outside world. You can block access to specific ports, only allow access to specific ports from an IP address or IP range. For example, you can use it to restrict access to SSH only to your office IP address to prevent anyone else from logging into your EC2 instance.