# Cannot RDP to Amazon EC2 instance(windows server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rdp, bionic

After launching windows 2016, Amazon EC2 instance,

I received `ec2-18-221-95-56.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com.rdp` file to connect to windows instance.

From my ubuntu laptop, Clicking the .rdp file, I receive this below message after providing password:

```
You requested an H264 GFX mode for server ec2-18-221-95-56.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com, but your libfreerdp does not support H264. Please check Color Depth Settings.
```

---

Ubuntu bionic laptop:

```
$ uname -a
Linux machine 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ran below commands, to resolve this problem(no luck):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp libfreerdp-plugins-standard
```

---

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and in remmina, i just change color depth setting to GFX RFX (32 bpp) and Name Quick Connect. I am able to connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried connecting to a Windows machine using a Linux OS using RDP, but I found something related to your issue that could help. It seems that by changing the color depth setting, should be enough to connect. I was reading this [blog](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1766495) and it seems that this could be a solution.

Procedure for the workaround:

- Click the little + in the upper-left corner of the window. It is a bit
  hard to see; the color scheme seems to be dark grey on grey.
- From here, choose a different color depth setting
- Click Save as Default, or enter other settings and click Save.

This was found by an user called Ian in that respective blog.

**Update**

In order to connect to your Windows VM, you need to right click on the instance, a choose connect. There you will find your public DNS, which you can use to connect to that machine. You will see the following dialog.

[image]

If you want your public IP, on your instance administration window, select the instance, and under **description** in the below menu, you will see it.

[image]

Comment: I could not find +, which window are you talking about?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not in that dialog, it appears before you try to connect. It seems to be quite hard to find.

Comment: Yes I read that blog, that blog also asks for reinstalling remmina package.. I could not do that. Please provide the instructions for the same

Comment: The other blog I found that could help you, is this one https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/issues/1584. It is quite hard to find information for this bug though. Not much on the Internet. Hope you can solve it.

Comment: I had been thru all this blogs.. how to launch remote desktop preference?

Comment: It depends on the application you are using. Although, I think you are using Remnia, because of the command lines. So, in this [link](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu) it seems that using Remnia you have to change the color depth when creating the connection. Please, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Installed RDP client remmina but struck in configuring RDP, because I created windows EC2 instance, but don't know the IP address of windows Ec2 to configure RDP

Comment: Ohhh, now I understand. I edited my answer with the required information. Hope it helps.

Comment: Shall I copy the public dns name of aws  as domain in rdp client?

Comment: it is working now... public dns name is confusing me on aws..`ec2-18-221-95-56.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` How do I interpret this?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit confusing! Good thing it is working now :)

Answer (score 1):

just change color depth settings.